# Add password to package in gradle

Tags: gradle

I packed a zip containing a list of webapps with gradle.

At the end, I would like to add a password to the zip.

I tried to user commandLine passing the linuz command "zipcloak", then the psw in required twice and I'm not able to send it to the command line:

```
commandLine ("zipcloak", zip_name + ".zip")
setStandardInput ("psw")
setStandardInput ("psw")
```

Maybe there is a better solution to do this...

Thanks

EDIT:

I progressed by adding this lines:

```
commandLine "zipcloak", "zipname.zip"
ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(bytes)
out.println("psw")
out.println("psw")
out.flush()
ByteArrayInputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes.toByteArray())
standardInput = input
```

Now the command is executed and I see on the console the request of the password, but I'm not still able to send a string to this request directly from the script, I have to add it manually on the console...

EDIT - SOLUTION FOUND:

I found the solution: instead of adding a password to an existing zip, I packed the zip WITH password

```
task encodeZip(type: Exec) {
    workingDir path_target_workspace
    commandLine "zip", "-P", "password", "-r", "zipname.zip", "file1", "file2", "fil3" .....
}
```

Hope it helps